# OkHttp - What is the difference between queuedCallsCount() and runningCallsCount()?

Tags: java, android, okhttp

What is the difference between `queuedCallsCount()` and `runningCallsCount()`?

`queuedCallsCount()`: Why always return `0` for me. In which cases it will not be `0`.

`runningCallsCount()`: Returns the number of running request for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OkHttp's Dispatcher can process up to 64 concurrent requests, 5 requests per host. Calls after this limit are queued (qeueudCallsCount()) and processed (runningCallsCount()) later.

Their docs are good:
[Github OkHttp3 Dispatcher.kt](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/7a641531c8e03b10dc4fbf9f2465775d7ecc7649/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Dispatcher.kt)

Comment: So the (qeueudCallsCount()) is for queued request, right?

Comment: Every request is queued when created, but it is usually executed (running) immediately. You queuedCallsCount() won't usually exceed the 64 limit, so that's why you get 0 queud calls. Don't forget to mark as accepted answer if it helped you :)